# Permanently change color based on ID and class on a hover event

Tags: jquery, css

I need a jQuery code to permanently change the color of text when I hover over it, based on a div's class or ID. So when I stop hovering on the div, the text color remains changed.

jQuery:

```
$("#notam").hover(function () {
    $("#notam").addClass("fboto");
    },
    function () {
        $("#notam").addClass("fboto");
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id='bulletin'>
    <div class='notesColor1'>
        notes1
    </div>
    <div class='notesColor1'>
        notes2
    </div>
    <div class='notesColor1'>
        notes3
    </div>    
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.notesColor{
    background-color: #CEDEFF;  
}

.notesColor1{
    background-color: #ADC4ED;  
}
```

[My JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/peparthi/c52zcLqe/3/)

Comment: This should probably be done with the CSS `:hover` pseudo-class. No need for jQuery or even vanilla JavaScript for this behavior.

Comment: @Tyler ,What i want is : on hovering i want to change the colour and i want that color remains the same even if i take the cursor off the text.

Comment: In that case I've edited your post some more to make it clear

Answer (score 3):

To do this in jQuery per your comments below, all you need to do is assign a class on the mouseover event:

```
 $(".notesColor1").on('mouseover', function () {
     $(this).addClass("hover");
 });
```

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/c52zcLqe/6/)

Comment: I want to have new color remains even when I take the cursor off.

Answer (score 0):

To get this behavior you need to use mouseover, not hover.
Here is a simple example:
http://jsfiddle.net/Lakvo3dm/
HTML:

```
<button class="cell white"></button>
```

CSS:

```
.white {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
}
.black {
    background-color: black;
}
.cell {
    width: 10px;
    height: 15px;
}
```

jQuery

```
$("button").mouseover(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("white");
    $(this).toggleClass("black");
});
```